# Error installing mysql server on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, apt, mysql

I am getting error installing mysql on ubuntu desktop 14.04 ( 64-bit)

I used following command

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-server
```

It asked me for password (and verification) and ended on following errors

```
Setting up mysql-server-5.5 (5.5.38-0ubuntu0.14.04.1) ...
initctl: Unknown job: mysql
```

Any suggestions would be helpful

Comment: I like this question rather than the proposed dupe. The question is clear, as is the solution, which is accepted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
sudo apt-get purge mysql-server
sudo apt-get purge mysql-common
sudo rm -rf /var/log/mysql
sudo rm -rf /var/log/mysql.*
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/mysql
sudo rm -rf /etc/mysql
sudo apt-get install mysql-server --fix-missing --fix-broken
```

Credits to [thefourtheye](https://askubuntu.com/questions/296946/upstart-cant-start-mysql)

Comment: This did not work for me.  I'm on Ubuntu Trusty using Crouton.

Comment: **Just a note for any future people with the same problem:** I tried installing it as root, but wouldn't succeed. But as a normal user and `sudo` install all the packages, it worked. Maybe this will help anybody in the future...