# Cannot install mysql server 5.5 on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: apt, package-management, mysql, dependencies

I have tried many ways to install mysql-server. I first tried installing by executing

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-client-5.5 mysql-server mysql-server-core-5.5
```

I was asked for root password, and that I did. But the install was not complete some unmet dependency came up. Very similar to in this [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/489815/cannot-install-mysql-server-5-5-the-following-packages-have-unmet-dependicies%22question%22). I have then tried different combinations and unmet dependency issue went away but I started getting this

```
Preparing to unpack .../mysql-server_5.5.43-0ubuntu0.14.04.1_all.deb    
Unpacking mysql-server (5.5.43-0ubuntu0.14.04.1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/mysql-server-5.5_5.5.43-
0ubuntu0.14.04.1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I have already tried removing and purging dependencies through various methods like in this [question 2](https://askubuntu.com/questions/525912/error-installing-mysql-server-on-ubuntu-14-04). I have also tried doing that via Aptitude and tried installing mysql-server again, but with no success.
Please help me out!

Comment: Remove the cached archive: `sudo rm /var/cache/apt/archives/mysql-server-5.5_5.5.43-
0ubuntu0.14.04.1_amd64.deb`

Comment: sudo rm /var/lib/mysql/debian-5.6.flag

Comment: I did as you said and I remooved the debian .flag file too. It installed successfully but gave error at setting root password. Running `mysql`  gave this error `ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)`. So I gave up and installed 5.6 mysql server and client via Aptitude. Thanks anyways

Comment: Than I have an answer for you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the cached deb file:

```
sudo rm /var/cache/apt/archives/mysql-server-5.5_5.5.43-0ubuntu0.14.04.1_amd64.deb
```

and try it again:

```
sudo apt-get install -f
sudo apt-get install mysql-client mysql-server
```

Alternatively, install version 5.6:

```
sudo apt-get remove mysql-server mysql-client
sudo apt-get install mysql-server-5.6 mysql-client-5.6
```

Comment: **Just a note for any future people with the same problem:** I tried installing it as root, but wouldn't succeed. But as a normal user and `sudo` install all the packages, it worked. Maybe this will help anybody in the future...

Answer (score 4):

`dpkg --get-selections | grep "mysql"`(It list all installed mysql in your system)

If still mysql installed In Your System remove it first by using following commands.

```
    sudo apt-get --purge remove mysql
    sudo apt-get autoremove mysql
    sudo apt-get autoclean mysql
```

check for /etc/mysql/my.cnf and /var/lib/mysql files. If these files still exist then remove them by using

```
  sudo rm -rf /etc/mysql/
  sudo rm -rf /var/lib/mysql/
```

Above two commands completely removes your MySQL data directory and configuration file.please sure before removing it.

Once update your system:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

After update install MySQL server

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-client mysql-server
```

Comment: Installing new version of config file /etc/init.d/mysql
Installing new version of config file /etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.mysqld
start: Job failed to start
invoke-rc.d: initscript mysql, action "start" failed
dpkg: error processing package mysql-server-5.6 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Setting up libhtml-template-perl (2.95-1) 
Setting up mysql-common-5.6 (5.6.27-0ubuntu0.14.04.1)
Processing triggers for ureadahead 
Errors were encountered while processing:mysql-server-5.6
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Comment: Tried all the steps , removed all the mysql related packages, still i get ":  dpkg: error processing package mysql-server (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                          Errors were encountered while processing:
 mysql-server-5.6
 mysql-server
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)