# MySQL installation fails and root password cannot be set

Tags: mysql

I am trying to install mysql server on ubuntu 14.0.4.

When I ran `sudo apt-get install mysql-server php5-mysql`
I got a message to set root password.

1. When I did not set a password, it kept asking for password
2. When I set a password, it mentioned that password has changed.

Output:

```
start: Job failed to start
invoke-rc.d: initscript mysql, action "start" failed.
dpkg: error processing package mysql-server-5.5 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Setting up libhtml-template-perl (2.95-1) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mysql-server:
 mysql-server depends on mysql-server-5.5; however:
  Package mysql-server-5.5 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package mysql-server (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.19-0ubuntu6.4) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mysql-server-5.5
 mysql-server
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Then I tried the following step but it failed:

```
root@jdm:/var/run/mysqld# sudo mysql_install_db
Installing MySQL system tables...
160312  2:14:01 [Warning] Using unique option prefix key_buffer instead of key_buffer_size is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use the full name instead.
160312  2:14:01 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 5.5.47-0ubuntu0.14.04.1) starting as process 21095 ...

Installation of system tables failed!  Examine the logs in
/var/lib/mysql for more information.

You can try to start the mysqld daemon with:

    shell> /usr/sbin/mysqld --skip-grant &

and use the command line tool /usr/bin/mysql
to connect to the mysql database and look at the grant tables:

    shell> /usr/bin/mysql -u root mysql
    mysql> show tables

Try 'mysqld --help' if you have problems with paths.  Using --log
gives you a log in /var/lib/mysql that may be helpful.

Please consult the MySQL manual section
'Problems running mysql_install_db', and the manual section that
describes problems on your OS.  Another information source are the
MySQL email archives available at http://lists.mysql.com/.


root@jdm:/var/run/mysqld# apt-cache policy mysql-server-5.5
mysql-server-5.5:
  Installed: 5.5.47-0ubuntu0.14.04.1
  Candidate: 5.5.47-0ubuntu0.14.04.1
  Version table:
 *** 5.5.47-0ubuntu0.14.04.1 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure why your having this issue but it sounds like a privilege issue with your folders not able to save your setting, I would backup all important files you have and do fresh install because on a fresh install you get to setup all the passwords and complete lamp environment and your done and working in just over an hour. Hope that helps

Comment: Thanks Vasko, but I tried this & didnt help. Is there some way to find the preconfigured root password & go ahead with the installatin?

Comment: I think this has been answered here http://askubuntu.com/questions/642422/cannot-install-mysql-server-5-5-on-ubuntu-14-04