# Can't find job mysql on crouton precise

Tags: mysql, upstart, chromebook, chroot

I'm using Ubuntu precise as `chroot` in my chromebook machine.

I'm trying to install `mysql` through `apt-get install mysql-server`.

The thing is, when I try to start it, it can't find the job:

```
(precise)mauriciogior@localhost:~$ sudo start mysql
start: Unknown job: mysql
```

OR

```
(precise)mauriciogior@localhost:~$ sudo /etc/init.d/mysql start
Rather than invoking init scripts through /etc/init.d, use the service(8)
utility, e.g. service mysql start
initctl: Unknown job: mysql

Since the script you are attempting to invoke has been converted to an
Upstart job, you may also use the start(8) utility, e.g. start mysql
```

OR

```
(precise)mauriciogior@localhost:~$ sudo service mysql start
Rather than invoking init scripts through /etc/init.d, use the service(8)
utility, e.g. service mysql start
initctl: Unknown job: mysql

Since the script you are attempting to invoke has been converted to an
Upstart job, you may also use the start(8) utility, e.g. start mysql
```

I tried everything I saw online, removing everything related to `mysql` and installing again.

I tried using `sudo initctl reload-configuration`, and everything on this post [Upstart can't start MySQL](https://askubuntu.com/questions/296946/upstart-cant-start-mysql)

Here is the dump of my installation:

```
(precise)mauriciogior@localhost:~$ sudo apt-get install mysql-server
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  php5-fpm php5-common
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following extra packages will be installed:
  libdbd-mysql-perl libmysqlclient18 mysql-client-5.5 mysql-client-core-5.5 mysql-common mysql-server-5.5 mysql-server-core-5.5
Suggested packages:
  tinyca mailx
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libdbd-mysql-perl libmysqlclient18 mysql-client-5.5 mysql-client-core-5.5 mysql-common mysql-server mysql-server-5.5 mysql-server-core-5.5
0 upgraded, 8 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/26.3 MB of archives.
After this operation, 94.9 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? 
Preconfiguring packages ...
Selecting previously unselected package mysql-common.
(Reading database ... 14874 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking mysql-common (from .../mysql-common_5.5.44-0ubuntu0.12.04.1_all.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libmysqlclient18.
Unpacking libmysqlclient18 (from .../libmysqlclient18_5.5.44-0ubuntu0.12.04.1_amd64.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libdbd-mysql-perl.
Unpacking libdbd-mysql-perl (from .../libdbd-mysql-perl_4.020-1build2_amd64.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package mysql-client-core-5.5.
Unpacking mysql-client-core-5.5 (from .../mysql-client-core-5.5_5.5.44-0ubuntu0.12.04.1_amd64.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package mysql-client-5.5.
Unpacking mysql-client-5.5 (from .../mysql-client-5.5_5.5.44-0ubuntu0.12.04.1_amd64.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package mysql-server-core-5.5.
Unpacking mysql-server-core-5.5 (from .../mysql-server-core-5.5_5.5.44-0ubuntu0.12.04.1_amd64.deb) ...
Setting up mysql-common (5.5.44-0ubuntu0.12.04.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package mysql-server-5.5.
(Reading database ... 15052 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking mysql-server-5.5 (from .../mysql-server-5.5_5.5.44-0ubuntu0.12.04.1_amd64.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package mysql-server.
Unpacking mysql-server (from .../mysql-server_5.5.44-0ubuntu0.12.04.1_all.deb) ...
Processing triggers for ureadahead ...
Setting up libmysqlclient18 (5.5.44-0ubuntu0.12.04.1) ...
Setting up libdbd-mysql-perl (4.020-1build2) ...
Setting up mysql-client-core-5.5 (5.5.44-0ubuntu0.12.04.1) ...
Setting up mysql-client-5.5 (5.5.44-0ubuntu0.12.04.1) ...
Setting up mysql-server-core-5.5 (5.5.44-0ubuntu0.12.04.1) ...
Setting up mysql-server-5.5 (5.5.44-0ubuntu0.12.04.1) ...
runlevel:/var/run/utmp: No such file or directory
initctl: Unknown job: mysql
150831 19:50:14 [Warning] Using unique option prefix key_buffer instead of key_buffer_size is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use the full name instead.
150831 19:50:14 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 5.5.44-0ubuntu0.12.04.1) starting as process 13351 ...
Setting up mysql-server (5.5.44-0ubuntu0.12.04.1) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin ...
ldconfig deferred processing now taking place
```

**EDIT**
I tried creating the file `/var/run/utmp` and installing it again... no success.